# Router Service error while Installing JFrog Artifactory

Tags: installation, jfrog-xray

I downloaded artifactory from official site and installed the rpm on my CentOS server using `sudo yum install -y jfrog-artifactory-pro-7.2.1.rpm`

However, it is throwing an error related to router-service:

Snippet from router-service.log

```
: Failed joining the cluster; Error: Error response from service registry, status code: 400; message: Could not validate router Check-url: http://::1:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping; detail: I/O error on GET request for "http:///:1:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping": URI does not specify a valid host name: http:///:1:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name: http:///:1:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping
```

Snippet from artifactory-service.log

```
Caused by: org.jfrog.common.RetryException: Error while trying to connect to local router at address ‘http://localhost:8046/access’: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessServerStartupValidator.convertToRetryException(AccessServerStartupValidator.java:54)
    at io.vavr.API$Match$Case0.apply(API.java:5135)
    at io.vavr.API$Match.option(API.java:5105)
    at io.vavr.control.Try.mapFailure(Try.java:602)
    at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessServerStartupValidator.pingAccess(AccessServerStartupValidator.java:44)
    at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.handleFunctionExecution(ExecutionUtils.java:99)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientException: Unable to connect to Access server: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I'm able to curl but while trying in browser, I'm getting a 500 error:

```
curl -I http://localhost:8081/artifactory
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /artifactory/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 13 Mar 2020 15:41:19 GMT
```

Error in Browser:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Artifactory failed to initialize: check Artifactory logs for errors."
  } ]
}
```

localhost is allowed for all ports.